# How do I plot tick marks inside a lattice plot

Tags: r, lattice

How do I plot tick marks inside of a lattice plot, opposed to the outside. "tcl = 0.5" seems to work for a normal plot; however not for my lattice dotplot.

Example of what I'd like to replicate in Lattice:

[image: Example of what I'd like to replicate in Lattice]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tick length is controlled by the `tck=` argument, which needs to be passed in to higher-level plotting functions via their `scales=` argument. Setting `tck=0` suppresses drawing of the ticks, while setting it to a negative number causes ticks to be drawn inside of the plot:

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10, 
       scales = list(y = list(tck=0), 
                     x = list(tck=c(-1, 0))))
```

[image]